# Schur's lemma for not necessarily irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

In the book "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" by Nielsen and Chuang, the following version of Schur's lemma is given, which does not assume irreducibility.

To explain the notation, $M_n$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. Of course, the operation in the groups is the matrix multiplication.

Lemma A2.2: (Schur's Lemma) Let $G \subset M_n$ and $H \subset M_k$ be two matrix groups of the same order, $|G| = |H|$. If there exists a $k$ by $n$ matrix $S$ such that $Sg_i = h_iS$ for some ordering of all elements $g_i \in G$ and $h_i \in H$, then either $S$ is the zero matrix, or $n=k$ and $S$ is a square nonsingular matrix.

Is the statement correct without some notion of irreducibility?
Can the above statement be reduced to the usual form of Schur's lemma by decomposing the matrices into block diagonal matrices?
Or does the assumed equality of orders somehow replace the otherwise usual irreducibility?

Comment: (1) No. (2) Yes. (3) No.